# Kind of increment on arrays in js

Tags: javascript

I want to do a grid calculation of numbers the grid is 30x30
so i came up with the idea of having 30 arrays with 30 numbers in it.
and now i'm looking for a way to go from array1 to array2 with a simple increment instead retyping it 30 times

```
var array1 = ['blue','red'];
var array2 = ['magenta','yellow'];
var curarray = 1;
console.log(array+curarray)
//something like the above (the example obviously doesn't work)
```

Comment: Use array of arrays instead. `var colors = [['blue','red'], ['magenta','yellow']]; var cur = colors[0]; cur = colors[1];`

Comment: @zerkms i think that'll work thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an array that holds all the arrays

```
var arr = [
    ['blue','red'],
    ['magenta','yellow']
];
```

Then you can access the data via its index (an array has an index automatically)

```
var curarray = 0;
console.log(arr[curarray]); // ['blue','red']
```